# Speedy SQL comparision (will position matter)?

Tags: operator-keyword

Is there any performance issue between the below queries because of the position of what is being compared - the one from system's value and data from hard-disk?

```
SELECT * FROM hashes WHERE hash_key='HASH_KEY' AND NOW() <= expires_on;
SELECT * FROM hashes WHERE hash_key='HASH_KEY' AND expires_on >= NOW();
```

Will `NOW() <= expires_on` and `expires_on >= NOW()` make any difference over large records?

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not make any difference.

What can make a difference is the position of `hash_key='HASH_KEY'` respectively to the one of `expires_on >= NOW()`.

Query at the end of the statement are executed before, so it's generally a good idea to put the one that filters the most at the end.